# User input from iPhone apostrophes do not come through

Tags: coldfusion

I'm developing a travel blog for a client where they can post blogs and allow user comment. All works well except when a user is using an iPhone to post. All apostrophes are not recognized and are stored as a rectangle. I have tested on a Macbook and apostrophes come through as well as any other keyboard. It seems to just be iPhone that's the problem. I'm using UTF-8. Any idea what I can use in a ColdFusion Replace() to fix this issue before the user input is stored to the database?

Comment: You need to do a hex dump of whatever is being stored in the DB. Also what kind of field are you saving the field in the DB?

Comment: I'm using MS-Access because it will be a low traffic low budget affair. The field that is storing the data is a Memo field

Comment: Find an iPhone with which to test.  Post an apostrophe, nothing else, to a test page.  On that page, run `writedump(asc(form.formfieldname));`  Then find an ascii table to see what the number represents.  If it's an apostrophe, have your client try it.  If it's something else, he might have his iPhone set up for smart quotes or something like that.  If so, there are functions out there to handle that.

Comment: I'm not an Apple fan so I just learned about Smart Punctuation. If nothing else I can have the client just turn off Smart Punctuation and that might be the fix. Thanks Dan for the dump code.

Comment: I wouldn't allow direct user input into a database, even if it's from a trusted user. There are a lot of risks for you client. There are a lot of good resources for how to treat user input. It's old and probably out-of-date, but check out https://github.com/teamcfadvance/ValidateThis for some ideas. Also look through https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries. You don't want to try to replace specific characters, because you'll keep chasing that forever. Allowing a specific set of characters is much easier in the long run than preventing characters.

Comment: Also, I'd be more than happy to see Access just disappear. It works well as a simple, personal desktop database. But when you start connecting it to SQL Server or connecting applications to it, it can get very wonky very quickly. Especially if you have more than one person or app trying to use it. Or if it grows larger than a  few dozen MB. Personally, if you're looking for an inexpensive db, you can throw up a MySQL db or use one of the built-in dbs like Derby (ACF) or H2 (Lucee). To me, Access is too fragile, and I don't like supporting it. Plus, it's query syntax is sometimes weird.

Comment: @Shawn I use Portcullis for input validation but that doesn't help me catch Apple Smart Punctuation characters

Comment: Smart quotes are not restricted to Apple.  MS Word has been producing them for years.  The answer to this question might help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783230/coldfusion-not-converting-accented-text-or-ms-word-chars.

Comment: @DanBracuk Do the smart quotes from Apple have the same encoding as the Microsoft ones?

Comment: Do the smart quotes from Apple have the same encoding as the Microsoft ones?  I have no idea, but my earlier comment tells you how to test this.

Comment: What about smart quotes? Emojis?  There are lots of other characters that may cause problems. I've been converting strings to ASCII7 using Junidecode (java). Here's the proof of concept script I wrote to test it: https://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/182608667654/coldfusion-unicode-junidecode-demo

Comment: As I don't have an iPhone, nor any inclination to buy one, I'll have to rely on someone else to tell me what the encoding for those Apple Smart Quotes is. :-) I'll have to check out James' suggestion when I get home later.

Comment: @JimButchart - But, back to my earlier comment, if Portcullis hasn't been updated in a while (and if it's still hosted from RIAForge (which is closing soon), then it probably hasn't), you'll want to look at something like FuseGuard that's kept up to date. However, you still want some depth to your filtering, so you'd also want to validate those inputs on your end as well. No user input should be trusted. Even legit, honest users can make a mistake that can completely bork your system and get you of bed at 3am.   Also, what version of ColdFusion are you using here?